# Plasmid with ITPG and pBR322 ori

Tags: cloning, plasmids

I'm looking for suggestions as my internet searches aren't turning up much.

I'm trying to find a plasmid that has the pBR322 origin, as it's low(ish) copy number and can tolerate large inserts. Additionally I need the plasmid to be inducible with a system other than the pBAD setup (e.g. IPTG would be fine, but if there is one that is more tightly repressed that would be preferrable as IPTG is leaky).

Lastly, I could do with it having a potentially obscure resistance cassette, but this is less of a problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check this https://www.embl.de/pepcore/pepcore_services/cloning/choice_vector/ecoli/vectorfeatures/

Comment: Gene 1985, Vol.40(2):183–190, doi:10.1016/0378-1119(85)90041-1 ‘ATG vectors’ for regulated high-level expression of cloned genes in Escherichia coli

Answer (score 1):

The [pET vectors family](https://www.csun.edu/~hcbio027/biotechnology/lec4a/petsys.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Just to add, if you're worried about leaky expression you can select a strain expressing T7 lysozyme from pLysS.